# Bootstrap 3 margin issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, margin

I would really appreciatd some help with this. I am having this margin issue and can't figure it out. It's probably something very simple, but I'm not seeing it.

The problem is that col-md-4 and col-md-8 are not in line.

[Here's an example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sjerabravo/GG8wJ/).

Thanks!

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4  text-center">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="cta">
                    <h3>Mek 's a Brew Lad</h3>
                    <p>A pint 'o mild. Tell thi summat </p>
                </div><!--end cta -->
            </div><!-- end col12 -->

            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="twitter">
                    <h3>Mek 's a Brew Lad</h3>
                    <p>A pint 'o mild. Tell thi summat </p>
                </div><!--end twitter -->
            </div><!-- end col12 -->                   
        </div><!-- end col4 -->

        <div class="col-md-8">
            <img src="img/bar.jpg" alt="Bar">
        </div><!-- end col8 -->              
    </div><!-- end row -->
</div><!-- end container -->`[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Include col-md-12 at the top to wrap both divs .
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class=col-md-12><!-- add this  -->
            <div class="col-md-4  text-center">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="cta">
                        <h3>Mek 's a Brew Lad</h3>
                        <p>A pint 'o mild. Tell thi summat </p>
                    </div><!--end cta -->
                </div><!-- end col12 -->

                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="twitter">
                        <h3>Mek 's a Brew Lad</h3>
                        <p>A pint 'o mild. Tell thi summat </p>
                    </div><!--end twitter -->
                </div><!-- end col12 -->                   
            </div><!-- end col4 -->

            <div class="col-md-8">
                <img src="http://placeimg.com/777/622/any" alt="Bar">
            </div><!-- end col8 -->


                </div><!-- add this  -->
        </div><!-- end row -->
    </div><!-- end container -->
```